# nlargest and nsmallest ; heapq python

Tags: python-2.7, heap

This is out of curiosity about the nsmallest and nlargest methods of  heapq.py module in python.

I was reading it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#) in the docs.

The documentation doesn't say how it does so (nsmalles/nlargest) on any iterable.

This might be a stupid question, but can I assume that these methods internally create a heap of the iterable data structure (may be using 'heapify' method) and then return the n smallest/largest elements?

Just want to confirm my conclusion. thanks!

Comment: For the exact implementation, you will need to delve into the C code. However, your assumption seems valid to me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algorithm for finding the `n` smallest or largest items from an iterable with `N` items is a bit tricky. You see, you don't create a size-`N` min-heap to find the smallest items.

Instead, you make a smaller, size-`n` max-heap with the first `n` items, then do repeated `pushpop` operations on it with the remaining items from the sequence. Once you're done, you pop the items from the heap and return them in reversed order.

This process take `O(N log(n))` time (note the small `n`) and of course only `O(n)` space. If `n` is much less than `N`, it's much more efficient than sorting and slicing.

The [`heapq` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/heapq.py) contains a pure-Python implementation of this algorithm, though when you import it, you may get a faster version of the code written in C instead (you can read [the source for that](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Modules/_heapqmodule.c) too, but it's not quite as friendly unless you know the Python C API).

Comment: ok I understood... instead if {heapify()} was used internally, then the space complexity would be {O(N)} [O of big N] and if N is large then it would be a lot of space compared to {O(n)} if n is small... so we save a LOT of space by sacrificing some performance in time... perfect...thanks! :)

Comment: It may not even take more time using this algorithm. That's because `n` is often a constant (not dependent on `N`). For any fixed `n`, `O(N log(n))` is equivalent to `O(N)`.