# Python - get N highest values in a list of weighted items

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a data structure consisting of a list of `tags`and `weights` pairs, like so:

```
tags = [['male vocalists', 4], ['Lo-Fi', 2], ['pop underground', 2], ['pop', 16], ['power pop', 99], ['post rock', 2], ['alternative', 59], ['electronic', 2], ['classic rock', 2], ['alternative rock', 14], ['pop rock', 2], ['baroque pop', 2], ['powerpop', 4], ['melodic', 2], ['seen live', 62], ['Bellshill', 3], ['singer-songwriter', 2], ['Favourites', 2], ['Teenage Fanclub', 4], ['emo', 2], ['glasgow', 12], ['Scottish', 73], ['indie pop', 27], ['indie', 100], ['00s', 3], ['new wave', 3], ['rap', 2], ['ambient', 2], ['brit pop', 2], ['90s', 14], ['britpop', 26], ['indie rock', 68], ['electronica', 2], ['shoegaze', 5], ['scotland', 11], ['post-punk', 3], ['Alt-country', 2], ['80s', 3], ['jangle pop', 7], ['guitar pop', 4], ['Pop-Rock', 2], ['rock', 31], ['favorites', 2], ['creation records', 3], ['All', 2], ['punk', 3], ['scottish pop', 2], ['british', 17], ['scottish indie', 2], ['slowcore', 2], ['UK', 6], ['jangly', 2]]
```

I know I can get tag with the highest value with:

```
top = max(tags, key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

which yields `indie`, correctly.

but how do I get N highest values, say, 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):

```
>>> import heapq

>>> heapq.nlargest(5, tags, key=lambda x:x[1])
[['indie', 100],
 ['power pop', 99],
 ['Scottish', 73],
 ['indie rock', 68],
 ['seen live', 62]]
```

or if you're only interested in the name:

```
>>> [name for name, _ in heapq.nlargest(5, tags, key=lambda x:x[1])]
['indie', 'power pop', 'Scottish', 'indie rock', 'seen live']
```

Answer (score 2):

Slice the first 5 elements from a descending sort.

```
sorted(tags, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)[:5]
```

MSeifert's answer is technically better algorithmically. With a large list of length `n` and comparatively small number of elements to take `m`, then `heapq.largest` may be quicker since it takes `O(n * log m)` time whereas sorting then slicing takes `O(n * log n)`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069490/nlargest-and-nsmallest-heapq-python) for a rough outline of `heapq.largest`'s algorithm). And then again, logs are almost negligible, so be sure to test if performance is a concern to you!

Answer (score 0):

`heapq` lets you do some really cool stuff like that:

```
In [168]: heapq.nlargest(5, tags, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
Out[168]: 
[['indie', 100],
 ['power pop', 99],
 ['Scottish', 73],
 ['indie rock', 68],
 ['seen live', 62]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sorted` function, or the `.sort` method on the list. Both take a `key=` parameter like `max`. Then you can take the lowest, or highest, batch.

```
top = sorted(tags, reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])[0:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
def printTopX(tags, X):
    print( sorted(tags, reverse=True, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0:X] )

printTopX(tags, 5)
```